# What is libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib and why is it being included in my app bundle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8

I've got an iOS app which I've recently switched to Xcode 8.
As part of that we switched from swift 2.2 to 2.3 (swift 3 will come later).

I've got an automated build pipeline which essentially runs `xcodebuild` to produce a release binary on a dedicated build machine, and after I sorted all that out (Xcode 8's automatic code signing really screws everything up), now when I upload my app to iTunes connect, it fails with this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'MyApp.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib' is not permitted. Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

Sure enough, if I unzip the .ipa file and have a look, there's `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib` sitting there.

If I archive/export for iTunes via Xcode, then it produces an app bundle which does not have `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib`, however all other builds of my app appear to have it. Even just doing a debug build within Xcode, then looking at the output shows that libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is sitting in my app's bundle, indicating that Xcode itself is definitely putting it there, not any part of my automated build script.

What is this file, why is it being put there, and what should I do about it?
I can modify my build script to delete this file for release builds, but I'm concerned that might affect the code signing process. I'll try it anyway and see what happens, but it feels like that's not quite the right thing to be doing.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I would imaging that is the swift binary that needs to be bundled with your app because if the incomplete ABI. Is Swift 2.3 supported for iTunes before the official release? I would imagine you are failing to validate because your app is not written in a currently supported language.

Comment: @RobertMasen: Xcode 8 GM was out last week, and the final was released sometime yesterday. Swift 2.3 and 3 are ready to use.

Comment: From looking at the logs, I think the step that adds the file is the CopySwiftLibs step, which invokes `builtin-swiftStdLibTool` with a bunch of parameters.

Three parameters are different between the Xcode build (which works) and the xcodebuild build (which have this file):

Xcode includes a flag `--unsigned-destination: <DerivedData>/BuildProductsPath/SwiftSupport`

xcodebuild includes two different flags:

1. `--resource-destination <path-to-built-app-bundle>`
2. `--resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib`

I don't yet know which handles to pull to make these similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could never get command line xcodebuild to ever work with automatic code signing. I assume because the automated build machine runs as a different account which is only accessed via SSH - It's never had "full" Xcode run as that user account and it doesn't have any certificates in it's Login keychain or anything like that.

I didn't want to use something like `shenzhen` because I've had nothing but bad experiences from those kinds of things in the past. The Xcode build system is complicated and fragile enough without having to add in more scripts and things that could go wrong or out of date.

Here's what I ended up doing to fix the problem (it's horrible, but it was the only thing I could find that made it work in the end)

1. In the automated build script, edit the `.pbxproj` to search and replace `Provisioning Style = Automatic;` with `Provisioning Style = Manual;`. Also replace `iOS Developer` with `iOS Distribution` for the code signing stuff in the same pbxproj file. These two things turn off automatic signing
2. Run `xcodebuild` to build (but not archive) the project in the same way I did in Xcode7 . Xcode compiles the app and signs it, but it's not valid yet, as it contains `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib` and also for some reason hasn't got any entitlements file
3. Delete `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib` from the app bundle (this invalidates the signature)
4. Generate an `Entitlements.plist` in the app bundle folder by extracting the entitlements bit from the provisioning profile (Like what [BlackBerry's SWSiOSResign.sh](https://github.com/blackberry/Secure-Work-Space/blob/master/Resigning-Scripts/Auto-Resigner-For-iOS/SWSiOSResign) script does)

   5. Re-sign the app bundle using `codesign --entitlements <file>`
   6. From there, use a similar technique to what [`bq/package_ipa.sh`](https://github.com/bq/ipa-packager/blob/master/package_ipa.sh) does and copy the SwiftSupport folder, then zip the file into an `ipa`.

I couldn't actually use `package_ipa.sh` file, I needed to re-implement similar logic instead because I need to reference `Swift_2.3.toolchain` to get the SwiftSupport from as my app is still swift 2.3 - not `XcodeDefault.toolchain` (which is swift 3)

It seems like I should be able to use `xcodebuild --archive` in combination with some other things to avoid some of these steps. I could never get that to work under Xcode7, but I might try again with XC8 if I have time

Comment: How you deleted ibswiftRemoteMirror.dylib from the app bundle? Can't find it

Comment: For some more help, go to https://coderwall.com/p/dgdgeq/how-to-re-sign-ios-builds.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I got ERROR ITMS-90171 because I am using custom frameworks.

> "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'MyFramework.framework/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib'

(I didn't get it for my application.)

I tried gym [but it got stuck at xcrun](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6365).  So I tried doing `rm -rf libswiftRemoteMirror` in the build phrase (with a custom run-script) for every custom framework I have and interestingly I didn't break anything: it worked.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit, how to do that?

Comment: Awesome!! This thing worked for me. Thanks nyan nyan

Comment: @gaurav414u great!

Comment: I had this issue going from Xcode 7.x --> Xcode 8 GM. Now in Xcode 8.1, using this technique in a dependent framework, the upload succeeds. I'm also using Swift 2.3 as an interim move toward Swift 3.

Comment: Here's the script I used in my case, in hope it helps someone else out: `rm -rf $SRCROOT/Carthage/Build/iOS/RocketData.framework/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib`

Answer (score 4):

Recently started using Swift for our project and got same error.

To find a root cause, I just did 'grep -Ril "libswiftRemoteMirror" .' in XCode.app  (I have 10.1 currently) and found ./Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XCLanguageSupport.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/swift-stdlib-tool.xcspec file. It says:

```
     // SWIFT_RESOURCE_DESTINATION and SWIFT_RESOURCE_LIBRARY allow us to copy
    // libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib into place so that memory debugging tools have access to it
    // on device.
    // We disable these options in "DEPLOYMENT" modes, so that the libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
    // does not make its way into archives submitted to the App Store.
```

So solution is simple - **in XCode target settings set Deployment Postprocessing to Yes** for your Release configuration (or whatever you use for build)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem after installing Xcode 8, by building via [shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen).

I decided to look at [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) as an alternative, and their [`gym`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/gym) program produces an ipa that can be submitted to Apple.

It was reasonably easy for me to replace the call to `ipa` (shenzhen's executable) with a call to `gym`, and the rest of my build-and-upload scripts worked without modifications.

If you prefer to build directly, I lifted the following from the `gym` readme. It produces an `.xcarchive` containing an `.app` file without the `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib`. I don't use that kind of flow myself, so I can't say how you would proceed from there.

```
xcodebuild \
  -scheme Scheme \
  -workspace Project.xcworkspace \
  -configuration 'Release' \
  -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
  -archivePath './Output.xcarchive' \
  archive
```

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the build setting and do as it is your problem will resolve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just Archive your build from Xcode  right click on archive file -> show in finder -> right click -> show package content -> product -> appliction -> copy .app file generate payload & upload using Application Loader.
It help in my case.

Comment: The point of my question is that I'm using an unattended command line build. There's no right-clicking to be had :-)