# ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure The binary file APP.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is not permitted

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm going to convert sift 2.2 to swfit 3.0 and uploading to itunes store then get one error.

I'm so tired with this error:-

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'ideaPitch.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

I have try some solution [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222102/iphone-app-submitting-error-itms-90171-invalid-bundle-structure-constants-o) but did not get proper result.

Any one can hlep me out.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480526/what-is-libswiftremotemirror-dylib-and-why-is-it-being-included-in-my-app-bundle

Comment: Thanks for comment but you given question solution not working for me so i have post new question. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you're generating the IPA on the command line.

Your best option is to simply use the Xcode7/8 default way to generate an IPA file:

```
xcodebuild -scheme $SCHEME clean archive $ARCHIVE_PATH
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $ARCHIVE_PATH -exportPath $IPA_PATH -exportOptionsPlist $EXPORT_PLIST
```

This approach will **automatically** take care of removing the `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib` from the resulting IPA file.

Alternatively you will have to remove the dylib on your own. You'll have to do it after creating the xcarchive but before exporting it to an IPA file: `rm -rf $APP_PATH/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib`

**EDIT**

In case you can't rebuild the IPA on your own and just want to remove the `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib` from it, you'll have to `resign` it: unzip the IPA, delete the dylib, re-codesign the bundle and zip it together again:

```
unzip AppName.ipa -d IPA
cd IPA
rm -rf Payload/$APP_NAME.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
codesign -vfs '$IDENTITY_NAME' Payload/$APP_NAME.app
zip -r --symlinks New_IPA.ipa *
```

Replace $APP_NAME with the name of your App bundle. Replace $IDENTITY_NAME with the name of the codesign identity used to originally sign the app. If unknown, you display it with `codesign -dvv Payload/$APP_NAME.app 2>&1 | grep Authority | head -1 | cut -d= -f2`.

The matching Certificate and Private Key must be present in your keychain for a successful resign. If your app uses special entitlements for push, associated domains etc., you'll have to pass a proper `--entitlements` param to the codesign command above.

Comment: I'm trying to uploading by Archive or Loader not from command line.

Comment: Okay. How are you creating the Archive and then exporting / uploading the IPA? If you would be doing it with the Xcode8.* UI (Product -> Archive etc.), there would be no libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib in the IPA's app bundle.

Comment: I have try to remove "libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib" form IPA its not working.

Comment: So somebody else build the IPA for you and you don't know how they did it and you can't rebuild the IPA on your own? That would be simplest solution

Comment: This is right why to remove "libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib" form IPA ? Why not working from Archive ?

Comment: You can of course remove the dylib from the xcarchive directly, but this will invalidate the app bundle's signature so you will have to re-codesign it like described above. If this doesn't help, please describe exactly what kind of files you have, how they were created and what exactly you want to do with them. Else this will continue to be looking for a needle in a haystack ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib` is copied to the App Bundle, but the App Bundle must not contain a binary other than the apps binary.

To fix this:

- In Xcode, remove "libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib" from everywhere in your project. Including "Copy Bundle Resources" and "Embedded Libraries".
- Add it to the target's `Link Binary with Libraries` build phase.
- Do not add it to the target's `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase.
- Clean & build & archive

Answer (score 3):

Problem is Solved !!!!

In my case I added the third party library  in Build Phase >> in link binery with library + also added in general tab Link  Embided  library + framework folder added all library

so this is wrong ....
I delete library from framework folder +  general tab Link Embided library
[image]

[image]

so the project is uploaded successfully

Comment: Thank you dude it's working for me. i'm using xcode 11.7.

Answer (score 1):

I battled with this on a new product for several days. Experimented with numerous different podfile changes, but for me it turned out to be that I was embedding the Pods_xxx.framework in the build when it should only have been linked.

Go to Targets and select your target, General tab, then make sure the Pods_xxx.framework IS NOT listed with the "Embedded Binaries" and is only listed with the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".